# I am working on authentication in laravel when i try to login it show error method not allowed http exception

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have followed a tutorial to add authentication to my application. I have a login route which has the method `post` and the form is also submitting as a `post` method. But whenever I click on the login button. Laravel throws an error of `MethodNotAllowed`. I assume that it is getting the method as a `get` request but the route is a post. Error is in the`compiled.php`.

**Route**

```
Route::any('signup',['as' => 'signup' , 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister']);

Route::any('loginForm',['as' => 'loginForm' , 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm']);

Route::post('login',['as' => 'login' , 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@login']);

Route::any('postRegister',['as' => 'postRegister' , 'uses' =>'Auth\AuthController@postRegister']);
```

**View**

```
     <form id="login" method="post" action="{{ route('login') }}">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
     <div class="form-group">
     <input type="email" placeholder="User Email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{old('email')}}"/>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Your Password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" {{--value="{{old('email')}}"/--}}>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="mj_checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="check2" name="checkbox">
   <label for="check2"></label>
   </div>
   <span> remember me</span>
   </div>
   </div>
       <div class="form-group pull-right">
   <span><a href="{{Route('reset-password')}}">forget password ?</a></span>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <input type="submit">
   </div>
   </form>
```

**{authentication code is here}**

```
   <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth; 
   //use \App\Http\Models\User;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
   use App\User;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
   use App\Http\Models\Company;
   use Hash;
   class AuthController extends Controller {
   /**
   * the model instance
   public function __construct(Guard $auth, \App\User $user)
   {
   $this->user = $user;
   $this->auth = $auth;
   $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['getLogout']]);
   }
    public function getRegister()
    {
    return view('public-pages.Home.signup');
    public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
     $company = new Company;
    $company-> companyName = $request -> companyName;
    $company-> email = $request -> email;
    $company-> password = Hash::make($request-> password);
    $company-> address = $request -> address;
    $company-> employeeName = $request -> employeeName;
    $company-> phone_no = $request -> phone_no;
    $company-> country = $request -> country;
    $company-> city = $request -> city;
    $company -> save();
   return redirect('loginForm');
   }
    public function showLoginForm()
   {
   return view('public-pages.Home.login');
   }
    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
   {
   if ($this->auth->attempt($request->only('email', 'password')))
   {
    return redirect('Private-pages.Company.cmp-home');
    } else {
     return redirect('/login')->withErrors([
     'email' => 'The credentials you entered did not match our records. Try again?',
     ]);
     }
     public function getLogout()
     {
     $this->auth->logout();
     return redirect('/');
     }
     }
```

Comment: Just a question, but why not use Laravel 5.2 and use the built in Authentication system?

Comment: Actually that is not working for me tried it with custom views. it did not work. One of my friend has used this code and it is working for him. Thats why i am trying it

Comment: Alright, built in works fine for me and many others so thought it might be best to use that rather than reinvent the wheel

Comment: Yes, you are right but time is limited and that is not working so i thought why not try this.

Comment: Which ironically isn't working either haha. Can you post your actual error?

Comment: Yes a bitter truth

Comment: are sure that the code you are using is not commented in you project ? is it exactly the same code that you have posted here?

Comment: no. the code is not  commented in my project